# C# DirectX Audio/Video Playback "VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM"

Tags: c#, video, directx, directshow, audiovideoplayback

I am trying to create a video player for MP4's with DirectX and it works on my computer but I tried my application on a netbook and this error code pops up in a `try{...}catch(Exception e){...}`.

```
Error in the application.
-2147220891 (VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM)
   at Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video.Open(String fileName, Boolean autoRun)
   at Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video..ctor(String fileName, Boolean autoRun)
   at Video_Player.Player.PeekWind_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This is some of my code.

```
Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video video = new Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video("C:\TestVideo.mp4", true);
video.Owner = ViewPane;
video.Size = new Size(Video.DefaultSize.Width, Video.DefaultSize.Height);
video.Audio.Volume = -2500;
video.Play();
```

Thank you for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM` is an error code returned by [underlying DirectShow layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390090), which indicates that it was unable to build playback pipeline. Which in turn means that some stream or format whatsoever could not be recognized and is typically missing a codec/filter component to read the data into decoded and presentation-ready state.

As you mention MP4, you presumably need a third party filter/codec installed since stock Windows does not offer a component for this within DirectShow API ([GDCL filters](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/) should fix this in Windows 7+ and in older systems you also typically need a third party H.264 decoder in addition).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I have a question about it though.  Where do I put the GDCL filters's dlls on my computer?

Comment: You put them anywhere, then you run once `regsvr32 xxx.dll` to register the binaries, from the daministrator's elevated command prompt. Then you don't move them from their location. That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am pretty new at this stuff (I had to research how to open an administrator's elevated command prompt :P) and you were a lot of help.

Comment: Sorry, one more question.  I installed a [third party H.264 decoder](http://www.free-codecs.com/DivX_H264_decoder_download.htm) and it still doesn't seem to work, do you know how to use it or do you know a better one?

Comment: Could you please add some information on your Q? What is the OS version, and is your application 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: My application is a 32 bit or at least that is what it shows when I see it in task manager.  My computer's OS is **Windows 8.1** with a **64 bit processor**.  If you want to try my program, you can download it [here](https://sites.google.com/site/openoceansoftware/home), click the download link and it opens an installer.  It may still be buggy though, but if you want to uninstall it afterwords, the only files are in the **"C:\OpenOceanSoftware" folder**.